# MVVM Light Messenger firing twice

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using Messenger to broadcast some information from a page code behind (I can't use eventtocommand) and messenger action is fring twice
here's my code
In viewModel

```
public CedareImpozitViewModel()
{
if (IsInDesignMode)
{
}
else
{
LoadListaPers();
LoadListaEntitati();        
Messenger.Default.Register<EntitateMessage>(this, AdaugaEntitateNoua);
}

UpdCedareCommand = new RelayCommand(() => UpdCedare(), () => this.CanUpdCedare());
```

}

From page code behind

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new EntitateMessage(cedare) { cedarenoua = cedare, entNoua = entity});
```

and EntitateMessage class

```
public class EntitateMessage : GenericMessage<CedareImpozit>
{
    public EntitateMessage(CedareImpozit parm)
        : base(parm)
    {
        entNoua = null;
        cedarenoua = null;
    }
    public CedareImpozit cedarenoua { get; set; }
    public Entitate entNoua { get; set; }
}
```

I am not navigating twice from my page.
Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: "I am not navigating twice from my page" <- Explain this, because the question title and this makes no sense

Comment: I saw cooments that I need to register message in OnNavigating because if you navidate second time on the same page it registers again.

Answer (score 2):

The experience shows that when such a thing happens, the cause is always that the registration occurred twice. Place a breakpoint on the Register method call to verify.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Hi Laurent I've verified this before posting here